# Automatic center for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Hello I am using a WP theme that to center the content I have to edit the padding-left because we dont know the width of the content area because change dynamically depending on the screen resolution.

The problem is tha due to different browsers have different scroll width and sometimes there is no scroll is very difficult to put a perfect center position calculated from "padding-left" and media queries.

I know different methods like margin: 0 auto, absolute positions or inline blocks that in other cases always work.

However at this time I need something like a Javascript that calculates the screen resolution and the content in the screen so the padding could change dynamically to a perfect center.

The link of the website is: http://www.fanonfire.com/magazine/

Right now is not centered but you can check that what we use to center the website is:

`.content_area {padding: 10px 0 0px 107px;}`

Changing the last number with different media_queries. But this do not generate a real center position and is very slow proccess. So I dont know if is posible to do this with Javascript and generate an automatic padding depending on the screen.

Thank you!

Edit: I tried with this without no luck (thank you ProllyGeek)

`var main_width=parseInt($("#main").width()) // get main width
var content_width=parseInt($(".content_area").width())  // get content area width
var my_padding=((main_width-content_width )/2).toString()
$(".content_area").css("padding-left",my_padding+"px") //set padding to the desired element`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get familiar with the following material:

http://www.demtron.com/blog/post/2009/01/14/Centering-a-DIV-Window-with-Cross-Browser-JavaScript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

fine if you want to do this using jquery here is a quick pseudo code

```
var container_width=parseInt($("#container").width()) // get container width
var content_width=parseInt($("#content").width())  // get content area width

var my_padding=((container_width-content_width )/2).toString()


$("#content").css("padding-left",my_padding+"px") //set padding to the desired element
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmBRp/3/

and if you want to see it centered replace padding-left with margin-left.

Comment: Thank you but with the actual template I am using I can not use a absolute position. I need something without change all the codex of the template to change the "padding-left" dynamically depending on the screen size. Thank you!

Comment: this is the simplest way to do it using jquery.

Comment: Thank you, something similar like that is how should work. However I tried to add that code to my header.php with the correct name of the classes (edited up) but is still not doing anything. Any idea?

Comment: are you sure that the content area is a child of container ?!

Comment: let me do a quick jsfiddle example

Comment: In the content area of the theme the first class is "#main" and then .content_area where the padding is added. But I am not sure if is going to work if I add this to the header and if is a problem that this two classes are in different css files. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you. I edited above the code I am using but still no luck. I think there is still something wrong with my code because of using "#" and "."

Comment: first # indicates an id , while . indicates a class , can you send a screenshot with your code ?!

Comment: can i know what do you get when you apply this code , you may try inspecting the page .

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem trying to center captions of varying lengths in a slideshow.

To center an absolute positioned element that has a dynamic width you can use transform: translateX. With prefixes this works in most modern browsers. Like so:

```
div {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);  
}
```